# Raspberry Can not get UDP data from Android smarphone

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a local network over wifi with a netgear wifi router, and there are several raspberry pis and an android phone on this network.

The raspberries can send and receive UDP data to each other, but the raspberries can not get UDP data from my android phone application.

the raspberry I want my phone to get UDP data from, through a socket:

```
class listen(Thread) :
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) #
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)    
        self.sock.bind(('', 5010))        
    def run(self) :
        global terminate
        while terminate == 0 :
            print ("wait for data from port 5010")
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024
            print data 
        self.sock.close
```

This works since I get data from an other raspberry.

the android phone implements this:

```
class SendThread extends Thread {

    int port = 5010;
    byte[] message = "welcome in Santa Clara".getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet;
    InetAddress address;
    DatagramSocket socket;

    SendThread() {
        try {
            // Create a datagram socket
            this.socket = new DatagramSocket();

            // Get the internet address of the specified host
            this.address = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.8"); //  the address of the rpi

            this.packet = new DatagramPacket(this.message, this.message.length, this.address, this.port);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (1 == 1)
        {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                System.err.println("Sending message ...");
                this.socket.send(this.packet);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have added in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

the thread are well started,  But the Rpi gets nothing.
No error from android app in java, no error from Rpi/python

Anything missing ?
Any clue I can look at in the router ?

Comment: Forget the question it works just after rebooting the raspberry. Don't know why this has made that com working. But at least it showed that the code is OK !

Answer (score 0):

Forget the question it works just after rebooting the raspberry. Don't know why this has made that com working. But at least it showed that the code is ok !